# sending data with ajax and no real route in node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am working on a web app with node/express. I have am email validation javascript file called validation.js. What I am trying to do is have an error message appear under the email input area once the user enters a wrong email. But It does, not seem to be doing so.

validation.js:

```
var INVALID_EMAIL = "The email you entered is invalid";
var EMPTY_EMAIL = "You did not enter an email";

exports.validateEmail = function (email, callback) {
    console.log("In validate email");
    console.log(email);
    var email = 0;

    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (email.length == 0) {
        err = EMPTY_EMAIL;
        callback(err);

    }
    else if (!email.test(emailFilter)){
        err = INVALID_EMAIL;
        callback(err);
    }
}
```

in app.js I added the route:

```
app.post("/validation/email", function(req, res) { validation.validateEmail(req) });
```

here /valiation/email is not a real view.

my login looks like this:

login.jade:

```
form(action="")
    key EMAIL
        input(type="text", name="username", id="email")
        br
        span(class="email-error-message")
        br
    key PASSWORD
        input(type="text", name="password", id="password")
        br
        span(class="pw-error-message")
        br
    input(type="submit", name="loginButton", id="login-button", value="LOGIN")
```

I haven't implements the password stuff yet so ignore it. But I have the span there so that I an output the error message in case a user inputs a wrong message.

finally, I have ajax calls in navigation.js:

```
$('#email').blur(function() {

console.log('inside click function in navigation.js');

$.post('/validation/email', $("#email").val() ,  function(data) {
     console.log('hello got here too');
    $(".email-error-message").html(data);
});
});
```

When I run this app, I get the console message that I am inside the click in navigation.js, but I do not get an error message when I leave the email input area warning me that I have used an invalid email. I have tried finding answers for this everywhere but I have been unsuccessful. I know it is possible to do so, but stuck on how to get it to do so.

Any help is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line.

```
app.post("/validation/email", function(req, res) { validation.validateEmail(req) });
```

validateEmail expects a callback function and there isn't one here.

Edited:
To solve the problem, I'd probably eliminate the callback all together since you're not really using it here to do anything other than send an error message back to the client.

here's what I might do:

Change the section where you define validateEmail to this

```
exports.validateEmail = function (req,res) {
```

And then:

```
var email= req.email  //Or whatever references where the email is in your request
```

and finally:

```
else if (!email.test(emailFilter)){
    err = INVALID_EMAIL;
    res.send(err);
}
```

Now you just need to pass req and res to your validate email function:

```
app.post("/validation/email", function(req, res) { validation.validateEmail(req,res) });
```

which is the same thing as:

```
    app.post("/validation/email",validation.validateEmail)
```

since req and res get passed in as arguments by default.

Comment: What would you suggest I do in the callback? I am kind of new to node

Comment: Well there's a few changes you'd need to make.

Comment: Yeah I made them, this helped me out a lot though. I got it to work though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should try out : https://npmjs.org/package/express-validator

In your app.js :

```
var ev = require('express-validator');
```

And use the module:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(ev());
// * Order is important.
```

Make a middleware and pass the error object :

```
 function validator(req, res, next) {

    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid Email').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid Password ! Mustbe Between 6-20 Charctersters').len(6, 20);

    var errors = req.validationErrors(true);
    if (errors) {
            res.render('login', { errors: errors});
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Setup route using this middleware :

```
app.post('/login', validator, doLoginStuff);
```

In jade template you can loop through error object and display error messages to the client from server side. In client side you can use any client side validation tool or Html5 form validation if you like.